# How to connect 2 combo boxes so that the content of one box effects the content of the second C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 combo boxes. One is used to select a company name like Apple and the second one should display only apple phones. However the second combo box keeps displaying the same samsung phone which is incorrect. How do I make the content of one combo box depend on the content of another?

I am trying to make a desktop application in C#.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Binding for the first combo box where you select the company
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select company_name from producers",connection);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("company_name ",typeof(string));
                dt.Load(reader);
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "company_name ";
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            //Binding for the second combo box where you select the product(phone)
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select model_name from model", connection);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("model_name ", typeof(string));
                dt.Load(reader);
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "model_name ";
                comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            string query = "select producerID,proizvodjac_name from producers";
            fillCombo(comboBox1, query, "proizvodjac_name", "producer_ID");
            comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null);


        }

        public void fillCombo(ComboBox combo, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember)
        {
            command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            combo.DataSource = table;
            combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int val;
            Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
            int i;
            
                string query = "select model_name from model where producer_ID= " + val + 1;
                fillCombo(comboBox2, query, "model_name", "producer_ID");
                
            
            

        }
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set `combo.ValueMember = valueMember` in the fillCombo() method.

Comment: Also, you should remove `+ 1`  so you have the following line in the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()` method:  `string query = "select model_name from model where producer_ID= " + val;`. Instead, set `int val = 1;` at the beginning of the method if you want to have a default value.

Comment: @MilosMrdovic i tried to add the combo.ValueMember = valueMember; and it gave me a Exception Unhadled error which says System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the new value member. (Parameter 'value')' .I tried looking for a solution but i can't find anything that helps.

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my first comment. Since you are binding to a DataTable, the problem is the `SelectedValue` is of type `DataRowView`. In order to get the actual value, you need to cast and select the row index where your key is located, like so: `Int32.TryParse((comboBox1.SelectedValue as DataRowView).Row[0].ToString(), out val);`

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much you fixed it. I have been trying to fix it for weeks. Do you have maybe a recmonedation for a tutorial or some other source where i can learn a bit better about c# console applications? I have a pretty shitty professor and all i can find are indian proggrammers who describe only a part of what i need.